# Django pre_save triggered twice

Tags: python, django, django-signals

I  am using django signals for data denormalization. Here is my code:

```
# vote was saved
@receiver(pre_save, sender=Vote)
def update_post_votes_on_save(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    """ Update post rating """
    # is vote is being updated, then we must remove previous value first
    if instance.id:
        old_vote = Vote.objects.get(pk=instance.id)
        instance.post.rating -= old_vote.value
    # now adding the new vote
    instance.post.rating += instance.value
    instance.post.save()
```

I cannot understand why, but when my `Vote` instance is being saved, `update_post_votes_on_save()` is being called twice. I thought there was a bug in my code, but saving through admin interface gives the same result.

Docs say something about [using `dispatch_uid` to prevent duplicate calls](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/#preventing-duplicate-signals), but I cannot understand if this is the case. How to use `dispatch_uid`? I've tried this, but with no luck:

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=Vote, dispatch_uid="my_unique_identifier")
```

Any ideas why function is being called twice and how to avoid it?

Comment: Search your codebase for where you are registering the signal - make sure it isn't registered twice

Comment: @chris: The dispatch_uid should prevent it from being registered twice.  

@silver-light: How have you verified that your handler is being called twice?

Comment: Check this out http://groups.google.com/group/django-users/browse_thread/thread/0f8db267a1fb036f Maybe you have duplicate registration too.

Comment: @shadfc, yes I did, using debugger in PyCharm

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm sorry, for the confusement, but `dispatch_uid` solved the problem, after all. Just remember, that you might have to restart the development server to see the effect, before asking a question on SO :)